# linked list of strings in C

Tags: c, memory-management, data-structures, linked-list, malloc

I am trying to create a linked list of strings in C and have had problems adding the first Node into the list. For whatever reason my program prints NULL even though I reference the head variable to newNode but it does not copy the string from struct pointer to struct pointer. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct stringData {
    char *s;
    struct stringData *next;
} Node;

Node *createNode(char *s) {
    Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->s = s;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}


void insert(Node *head, Node *newNode) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        head->s = newNode->s;
        head = newNode;
    }
}

void printList(Node *head) {
    while (head != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", head->s);
        head = head->next;
    }
}



int main()
{
    Node *head = createNode(NULL);

    Node *a = createNode("A");
    insert(head, a);

    printList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (head == NULL) {head->s = newNode->s;` pointers don't work this way. If `head` points to nothing, you can't touch `head->anything`, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Evey other linked-list post, (and there are thousands of them), has the 'modified local head only' bug:(

Comment: Since your code is incorrect, it is not clear whether you are trying to insert the new node to the start of the list, or to the end of the list. If you insert new nodes to the start of the list, `printList` will print the strings in the reverse order they were inserted (LIFO order). If you insert new nodes to the end of the list, `printList` will print the strings in the same order they were inserted (FIFO order). For LIFO ordering of (singly) linked lists, it is common to have a variable pointing to the first (head) node of the list, and another variable pointing to the last (tail) node.

Answer (score 2):

Following code snippet is wrong:

```
void insert(Node *head, Node *newNode) {...}
...
insert(head, a);
```

You need to pass the pointer by reference. Currently you are changing local copy (argument).

**Fix**
Change your `insert` as:

```
void insert(Node **head, Node *newNode) {...}
```

And call as:

```
insert(&head, a);
```

**What else**
Atleast `insert` (and possibly) more functions are not fool-proof (guaranteed null pointer dereference, `else` case not handled etc). You need to debug and fix many such cases. Working your approach properly on paper before coding may help.

Comment: upticked. I concur, but that function needs a lot more work than that. It directly dereferences a NULL pointer as it is now, and does nothing (with or without  a pass-by-reference solution) when non-null.

Comment: @WhozCraig Right, the order is bad and handling of `else` case is missing. But then I want to hint the OP and help him fix the code instead of fixing the code. But yes. I will mention this in my answer.

Comment: I don't think this is at all the intention.  It's simply a bad parameter name "head".  He didn't want to modify `head` -- it's a dummy head list, and he meant to alter `head->next`.

Comment: @paddy Then what's the purpose of `head = newNode;`?

Comment: I am certain they meant `head->next = newNode`.  But maybe you're right.  Maybe it just looks like this is a dummy-head list, when actually it's what you thought.  The code could go either way.  The `printList` function suggests it's not dummy-head.  The `insert` function shows a total lack of understanding of either style of list.

Comment: @paddy Yes only the person who wrote the code knows the real intention. But the implementation is erroneous.

Comment: Thanks when I made the changes it still doesn't copy the address from newNode into head `void insert(Node **head, Node *newNode) {
 
 if (head == NULL) {
  head = &newNode;
 }
}` I was using the head in main as a reference to the first item in the list so I can traverse it later. I left the else clause out of insert because I wanted to get this working first. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified version of the code that gives an example of inserting new nodes at both the start of a list and the end of a list.  In fact, the `insert` function could be used to insert a new node at any position in the list, since all it needs is a pointer to a link and a pointer to the node to be inserted.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct stringData {
    char *s;
    struct stringData *next;
} Node;

Node *createNode(char *s) {
    Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->s = s;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}


void insert(Node **link, Node *newNode) {
    newNode->next = *link;
    *link = newNode;
}

void printList(Node *head) {
    while (head != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", head->s);
        head = head->next;
    }
}



int main(void)
{
    Node *head = NULL;
    Node *tail = NULL;
    Node *n;

    n = createNode("B");
    // First node at start of list - head is updated.
    insert(&head, n);
    // First node is also the tail.
    tail = n;

    n = createNode("A");
    // Insert node at start of list - head is updated.
    insert(&head, n);

    n = createNode("C");
    // Insert node at end of list.
    insert(&tail->next, n);
    // Update tail.
    tail = n;

    printList(head);
    return 0;
}
```